# add the remainder of those left out of the query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have five tables:

1. Teacher
   ID
   Name
2. Ct
   TID
   CID
3. Course
   ID
   Name
4. RC
   SID
   CID
5. Student
   ID

Name

The tables are beside the number. I have already written a query to find the teacher id, teacher name, student id and student name below:

```
select a.ID,a.name, c.SID,d.Name
from teacher a 
join ct b on a.ID = b.TID
JOIN rc c on B.CID = C.CID 
JOIN student D on c.SID = D.ID
```

there are 500 teachers and 2500 students. 300 teachers are teaching courses and 2000 students are taking course. I would like to include the teachers who are not teaching and the students who are not taking courses to this query. The ones not in the first query are actually doing research. How would I come up with a query to include the rest of those not currently included?

Comment: the ct table stands for courses taught and rc stands for registered coursed by student. each table is right beside the number with its two columns

Answer (score 1):

First, write the query with reasonable table aliases so it is easier to read.  Then, I think the simplest solution might be:

```
with ts as (
      select t.ID, t.name, s.ID as sid, s.Name as sname
      from teacher t join
           ct
           on t.ID = ct.TID join
           rc 
           on rc.CID = ct.CID join
           student s
           on rc.SID = s.ID 
     )
select ts.*
from ts
union all
select t.id, t.name, null, null
from teacher t
where not exists (select 1 from ts where ts.id = t.id)
union all
select null, null, s.id, s.name
from student s
where not exists (select 1 from ts where ts.sid = t.sid);
```

You can eliminate one of the `union all` by using `left join`s.  You could eliminate both by using `left join` and `full join`:

```
select t.ID, t.name, s.ID as sid, s.Name as sname
from teacher t left join
     ct
     on t.ID = ct.TID left join
     rc 
     on rc.CID = ct.CID full join
     student s
     on rc.SID = s.ID ;
```

This also works.  But if you wanted to filter the results in any way, I find the the `union all` version is simpler to adjust.